# How to make an image inside a modal clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have button that displays a modal which contains many icons, and I want it when I click one of the images it will indicate that I have clicked it. But I don't have any idea how to implement it.

So far this is how my modal looks like. 
[image: Modal Image]

My objective:To put an indicator that I have clicked it.
[image]

**CODE**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left">
            <?php 
                $tokenSql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM topplayer WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ");
                $retToken = mysql_fetch_assoc($tokenSql);
                $token = $retToken['token'];
                echo ("<b>Tokens : $token </b><br>");
             ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
        </div>
     </div>
        <div class="row ml">
            <?php 
                $sendGiftSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE isDelete = 'false' ORDER BY price ");
                while($sendGift = mysql_fetch_assoc($sendGiftSql)){
                        $giftIMG = $sendGift['img_path'];
                        echo("
                            <div class='col-xs-4 mb'>
                              <br>
                              <img id='edgiftPhoto'  class='center-block' alt='No image' src='$giftIMG' style='height:120px; width: 120px'/>&nbsp;
                            </div> 
                    ");
                }
            ?>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide code examples (preferably verbatim), otherwise it is very difficult to suggest solutions.

Comment: Google javascript calculator sourcecode.  This should give you some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Generic, super super super simple solution. No need for a plugin.

JS:

```
$('.modal-body').on('click','img',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
})
```

CSS:

```
.clicked{
    border:1px solid black;
    //style it however you want
}
```

Comment: sir I tried integrating the code  you gave but it doesnt work.

Comment: @KaelJasper it does work, https://fiddle.jshell.net/8da4awjf/ check your console log for errors and make sure that the script is DOM ready